# Multiple INNER JOIN not working

Tags: php, sql, join, pdo

I can't get both INNER JOINS working. Data is being displayed when I only use the first INNER JOIN but there's nothing being displayed when I add the second INNER JOIN.

Here's the code I'm using where the url would be: **website.com/matchdetails/season/match_id**

```
     <?php
     $db = new PDO('mysql:host=db.xx.xx;dbname=xx','xx','xx'); 

     $sth = $db->prepare("
     SELECT *
     FROM 
         matchdetails AS md 
     INNER JOIN 
         players AS p
             ON 
             (p.player_id = md.player_id) 
     INNER JOIN
         matches AS m
             ON
             (m.match_id = md.match_id) 
              WHERE (CONCAT_WS('/', season, match_id)) = :season");
     $sth->execute(array(':season' => substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1)));
     foreach($sth as $row) {?>
     <?php echo 'Name '. $row['name'] . '<br/>'; ?> 
     <?php echo 'Goals ', $row['goals'] . '<br/>'; ?> 
     <?php echo 'Assists ',$row['assists'] . '<br/>'; ?> 
     <?php echo 'VVO Score ',$row['vvo_score'] . '<br/>' . '<br/>'; ?> 
     <?php }?>
```

My database structure is:

**Table matches**

[image]

**Table matchdetails**

[image]

**Table players**

[image]

Comment: Without showing sample data, we have no reason to assume that rows should be returned.  Do you have some rows from each of the tables that would match your conditions?

Comment: Can you explain this line to me?
WHERE REPLACE(CONCAT_WS('/', season, match_id), ' ', '/') = :season")

Comment: Do any other queries work? Do you have a similar query that produces some output but doesn't giive you exactly the results you need? Can you post it? What's the main difference between the query that works and this one that doesn't?

Comment: @AverageMarcus Changed that to WHERE (CONCAT_WS('/', season, match_id)) = :season"); That was old code for my players page, so I didn't have any problems with players with double last names.

Comment: Is there a reason you have no closing `"` at `WHERE (CONCAT_WS('/', season, match_id)) = :season");`?

Comment: I don't see the point of doing it this way. Why not just explode your path and do a "WHERE match_id = :match_id AND season = :season"? Much easier to debug.

Comment: @vichle Ok, I tried that but I think I've got it wrong since its not working.: `WHERE match_id = :match_id AND season = :season");
$sth->execute(array(':season' => substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1)));`   error: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: @Linoff: I've updated my post with screens of my db structure.

Comment: I think I understand why it isn't working. Table matches doesn't have a player_id column so there's no way to display data since match_details takes its data from the player_id column. Does this mean I have to make an extra query to INNER JOIN matches with matchdetails and be able to display data from both tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ON (p.player_id = m.player_id)`, m is the table 'matches' and 'matches' has no column whose name is 'player_id'.